# grabbing a column from a list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, caml

I'm having an issue when I'm trying to grab a column I made in the tasks list (it's a lookup column). for some reason when i'm try to access it with javascript i always get an exception that it isn't initialized. i run the caml query and that run ok, and i am able to get some information from the task list, like title and status, but not the column i made.

Here is my code. The problem comes in when i try to access "Contact ID" in the linkInfo method. any help would be great. Thank You.

```
function test() {

         var newClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var oWebsite = newClientContext.get_web();
        this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

        var Caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var taskCaml = new SP.CamlQuery();

        Caml.set_viewXml('<View></View>');

        var getContactList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Contacts");
        var getTasksList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");

        this.contactList = getContactList.getItems(Caml);
        this.taskList = getTasksList.getItems(Caml);

        newClientContext.load(contactList);
        newClientContext.load(taskList);

        newClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.linkInfo), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }


    function linkInfo() {

        var contactEnum = contactList.getEnumerator();
        var taskEnum = taskList.getEnumerator();
        var holder = '<br/>';
        alert(contactList.get_count());
        while (contactEnum.moveNext())
        {
            var oContact = contactEnum.get_current();
            holder += oContact.get_item('Title')+": ";

            while (taskEnum.moveNext()) {
                var oTask = taskEnum.get_current();

                if (oContact.get_id() == oTask.get_item('Contact ID')) {
                     holder += oTask.get_item('Title') + ", " ;
                }

            }

            holder += "<br/>";
            taskEnum = taskList.getEnumerator();
        }
        document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = "<p>" + holder + " </p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your referencing the Display Name of the column instead of the Internal name. In the get_item() method, you will have to pass the Internal name of the `Contact ID` field. It will never contain spaces. It should most probably be something like `Contact_x0020_ID`. You can find out the exact internal name of the column with the steps mentioned in the following link:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/Getting%20the%20Field%20by%20the%20Internal%20Name.aspx

Comment: Thank You, you're right. I checked the source and the ID of my field was as you said it was :)